# Error in VBA code in Access 2016

Tags: ms-access, vba

Below is a code that is supposed to count number of occurrences of a given substring in a given string. I did not write it, it was taken from a web page which link I will provide later.

```
Function StringCountOccurrences(strText As String, strFind As String, _
                                Optional lngCompare As VbCompareMethod) As Long
' Counts occurrences of a particular character or characters.
' If lngCompare argument is omitted, procedure performs binary comparison.
'Testcases:
'?StringCountOccurrences("","") = 0
'?StringCountOccurrences("","a") = 0
'?StringCountOccurrences("aaa","a") = 3
'?StringCountOccurrences("aaa","b") = 0
'?StringCountOccurrences("aaa","aa") = 1
Dim lngPos As Long
Dim lngTemp As Long
Dim lngCount As Long
    If Len(strText) = 0 Then Exit Function
    If Len(strFind) = 0 Then Exit Function
    lngPos = 1
    Do
        lngPos = InStr(lngPos, strText, strFind, lngCompare)
        lngTemp = lngPos
        If lngPos > 0 Then
            lngCount = lngCount + 1
            lngPos = lngPos + Len(strFind)
        End If
    Loop Until lngPos = 0
    StringCountOccurrences = lngCount
End Function
```

The question is why is it giving an error message that I may have entered a comma without preceding value or identifier?

A web page the code was taken from: http://codevba.com/visual-basic-source-code/vb-string/count_occurrences_in_a_string.htm#.WlAPpzdG2Uk

Thank you.

Comment: Please copy the code to the question

Comment: @Bsalex  – I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is perhaps another way to write the function:

```
Function StringCountOccurences(strTxt As String, strFnd As String, Optional lngCmp As VbCompareMethod) As Long
    If Len(strFnd) <> 0 Then
        StringCountOccurences = (Len(strTxt) - Len(Replace(strTxt, strFnd, "", , , lngCmp))) / Len(strFnd)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Although, reopening a database solved the problem (which actually never existed in the code itself), you provided very neat code as a better replacement for the code I provided, so your answer deserves to be picked as the best. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Well, reopening a database solved the problem.